# sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an error(datatype mismatch error) while inserting values into database:
front end code passing the data to `database(back end)`:

```
    def add_data():
        if ID_NO.get()!=0:
            Clg_back_end.Add_data(ID_NO.get(),NAME.get(),CLASS.get(),BRANCH.get(),SKILLS.get(),GENDER.get(),C_GPA.get(),PH_NUM.get())
            Clg_List.delete(0,END)
            Clg_List.insert(END,(ID_NO.get(),NAME.get(),CLASS.get(),BRANCH.get(),SKILLS.get(),GENDER.get(),C_GPA.get(),PH_NUM.get()))
```

**Backend code:**

```py
def Add_data(Id_no,Name,Class,Branch,Skills,Gender,C_G_P_A,Ph_no):
    con=sqlite3.connect('Clg.db')
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO Clg VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(Id_no,Name,Class,Branch,Skills,Gender,C_G_P_A,Ph_no))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Keerthi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Keerthi\Desktop\py_learn\Clg_database\Clg_front_end.py", line 48, in add_data
    Clg_back_end.Add_data(ID_NO.get(),NAME.get(),CLASS.get(),BRANCH.get(),SKILLS.get(),GENDER.get(),C_GPA.get(),PH_NUM.get())
  File "C:\Users\Keerthi\Desktop\py_learn\Clg_database\Clg_back_end.py", line 14, in Add_data
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO Clg VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(Id_no,Name,Class,Branch,Skills,Gender,C_G_P_A,Ph_no))
sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message, there is a datatype mismatch while you insert the data into your table. It may happen when you try to insert a value of specific type into a column that doesn't support this type and the value can't be converted automatically by your db (for example, when you try to insert a `string` value into a column of type `int`).

Try to print the datatypes of your data you're trying to load (`print(type(Id_no)), print(type(Name)), etc..)` and check if it's compatible with the column datatype of your table.

Comment: Thankyou,for your answer,datatype error is solved and i got another error:sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Comment: Great! If it helped you, please consider upvote/accept the answer in order to help other developers who struggling with similar issue.